# Can "Find Activity" automatically shows result with set parameters without going into selection every time?

Tags: search, search-results, activities, custom-search

For my volunteers I want to create an activity search based on set parameters, i.e. Phone, email. & scheduled. So they do not need to select parameters everytime.

If I enter &force=1 in the url the search automatically executes search function. Is there any shortcut like this for above criteria?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with an Activity Report. **Reports menu > Contact reports > Activity Report**. Set your parameters then save as a new report.

Comment: problem with report is, there is no bulk action available from there. Also need to give use permission to access reports.

Answer (score 1):

Can you create a new navigation menu item and add &force=1 to the url to that menu item?

I'm not sure what you mean by "set parameters"